# How to skip quoted text in regex (or How to use HyperStr ParseWord with Unicode text ?)

Tags: regex, delphi

I need regex help to create a delphi function to replace the HyperString ParseWord function in Rad Studio XE2. HyperString was a very useful string library that never made the jump to Unicode. I've got it mostly working but it doesn't honor quote delimiters at all. I need it to be an exact match for the function described below:

> function ParseWord(const Source,Table:String;var Index:Integer):String;
>
> Sequential, left to right token parsing using a table of single
>   character delimiters.  Delimiters within quoted strings are ignored.
>   Quote delimiters are not allowed in Table.
>
> Index is a pointer (initialize to '1' for first word) updated by the
>   function to point to next word.  To retrieve the next word, simply
>   call the function again using the prior returned Index value.
>
> Note: If Length(Resultant) = 0, no additional words are available. 
>   **Delimiters within quoted strings are ignored**. (my emphasis)

This is what I have so far:

```
function ParseWord( const Source, Table: String; var Index: Integer):string;
var
  RE : TRegEx;
  match : TMatch;
  Table2,
  chars : string;
begin
  if index = length(Source) then
  begin
    result:= '';
    exit;
  end;

  // escape the special characters and wrap in a Group
  Table2 :='['+TRegEx.Escape(Table, false)+']';
  RE := TRegEx.create(Table2);
  match := RE.Match(Source,Index);
  if match.success then
  begin
    result := copy( Source, Index, match.Index - Index);
    Index := match.Index+match.Length;
  end
  else
  begin
    result := copy(Source, Index, length(Source)-Index+1);
    Index := length(Source);
  end;
end;

  while ( Length(result)= 0) and (Index<length(Source)) do
  begin
    Inc(Index);
    result := ParseWord(Source,Table, Index);
  end;
```

cheers and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my original code I was looking for the delimiter and taking everything up to that as my next match, but that concept didn't carry over when looking for something within quotes. @Stephan's suggestion of negating the search eventually lead me to something that works. An additional complication that I never mentioned earlier is that HyperStr can use anything as a quoting character. The default is double quote but you can change it with a function call.

In my solution I've explicitly hardcoded the QuoteChar as double quote, which suits my own purposes, but it would be trivial to make QuoteChar a global and set it within another function. I've also successfully tested it with single quote (ascii 39), which would be the tricky one in Delphi.

```
function ParseWord( const Source, Table: String; var Index: Integer):string;
var
  RE : TRegEx;
  match : TMatch;
  Table2: string;
  Source2 : string;
  QuoteChar : string;
begin
  if index = length(Source) then
  begin
    result:= '';
    exit;
  end;

  // escape the special characters and wrap in a Group
  QuoteChar := #39;
  Table2 :='[^'+TRegEx.Escape(Table, false)+QuoteChar+']*|'+QuoteChar+'.*?'+QuoteChar ;
  Source2 := copy(Source, Index, length(Source)-index+1);
  match := TRegEx.Match(Source2,Table2);
  if match.success then
  begin
    result := copy( Source2, match.index, match.length);
    Index := Index + match.Index + match.Length-1;
  end
  else
  begin
    result := copy(Source, Index, length(Source)-Index+1);
    Index := length(Source);
  end;
  while ( Length(result)= 0) and (Index<length(Source)) do
  begin
    Inc(Index);
    result := ParseWord(Source,Table, Index);
  end;

end;
```

This solution doesn't strip the quote chars from around quoted strings, but I can't tell from my own existing code if it should or not, and I can't test using Hyperstr. Maybe someone else knows?

Comment: I wasn't sure of the SO protocol regarding who to give the answer to. I added the solution as a separate answer because I couldn't format it properly as a comment to @Stephan's answer, but he definately lead me to it.

Answer (score 1):

I would try this regex for `Table2`:

```
Table2 := '''[^'']+''|"[^"]+"|[^' + TRegEx.Escape(Table, false) + ']+';
```

**Demo:**
This demo is more a POC since I was unable to find an online delphi regex tester.

- The delimiters are the `space` (ASCII code `32`) and `pipe` (ASCII code `124`) characters.
- The test sentence is:

> toto titi "alloa toutou" 'dfg erre' 1245|coucou "nestor|delphi" "" ''
>   
>   http://regexr.com?32i81

**Discussion:**
I assume that a quoted string is a string enclosed by either two single quotes (`'`) or two double quotes (`"`). Correct me if I am wrong.

The regex will match either:

- a single quoted string
- a double quoted string
- a string not composed by any passed delimiters

**Known bug:**
Since I didn't know how ParseWord handle quote escaping inside string, the regex doesn't support this feature.

For instance :

- How to interpret this `'foo''bar'` ? => Two tokens : `'foo'` and `'bar'` OR one single token `'foo''bar'`.
- What about this case too : `"foo""bar"` ? => Two tokens : `"foo"` and `"bar"` OR one single token `"foo""bar"`.

Comment: this didn't work as given but did lead me to the solution. I'm including the complete solution as a separate entry, but all credit goes to you.